# how to build a mobile website using html on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mobile, web

I'm working on a simple mobile website for a hotel.they don't need much dynamic feature.most are simple HTML.So my question are as below.

1. I find it's hard to debug mobile website on Ubuntu.cause you know ,desktop browser are to big to show a mobile website.each time i need to put it on a server.then using a phone to test the mobile website.is't too annoy.is there a better way to do this?
2. On windows u have Dreamweaver to change the css style.but on Ubuntu can I find a tool like Dreamweaver?
3. is any any JavaScript code for animation for a mobile website.
4. Jquery mobile is a good js lib to create the basic element in webpages.but if I want to do some transition between pictures.how could I do that.

PS:if you want to use php to send a email to a email address how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome you can emulate a mobile device, the viewport and user agent will adjust to desired device. In your developer tools you have something called Emulation where you can change your device.

[Link!](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/mobile-emulation)

To send a email with PHP, check the documentation:
[Link to php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: thanks helpful for me .i'm totally a new guy oh, how about a css fiddle tool on ubuntu like dreamweaver on windows

Comment: @atekul What I think you mean by css fiddle, chrome also have that. Just right click on a element and inspect it. Then you can tweak and play around with the page css. You should really look into chromes dev tools, they're really great!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I would reccomend you start with a resposive framework. There are plenty of great options, including [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) , [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) or [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com)

From what you describe about your requirements, responsive is going to be a good fit for your client and you'll future-proof your design.

Then with a responsive design, you can test everything in a standard web browser by making the viewport or window wider or smaller.

Good luck!